# Using opensource Clamav engine

Tags: c++, c

I have just started using the open source antivirus **Clamav**, i am using **Microsoft visual studio 2010,** there is an example given in the code i want to start the coding from that example, the code is given below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <clamav.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
int fd, ret;
unsigned long int size = 0;
unsigned int sigs = 0;
long double mb;
const char *virname;
struct cl_engine *engine;


if(argc != 2) {
printf("Usage: %s file\n", argv[0]);
return 2;
}

if((fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY)) == -1) {
printf("Can't open file %s\n", argv[1]);
return 2;
}

if((ret = cl_init(CL_INIT_DEFAULT)) != CL_SUCCESS) {
printf("Can't initialize libclamav: %s\n", cl_strerror(ret));
return 2;
}

if(!(engine = cl_engine_new())) {
printf("Can't create new engine\n");
return 2;
}

/* load all available databases from default directory */
if((ret = cl_load(cl_retdbdir(), engine, &sigs, CL_DB_STDOPT)) != CL_SUCCESS) {
printf("cl_load: %s\n", cl_strerror(ret));
close(fd);
    cl_engine_free(engine);
return 2;
}

printf("Loaded %u signatures.\n", sigs);

/* build engine */
if((ret = cl_engine_compile(engine)) != CL_SUCCESS) {
printf("Database initialization error: %s\n", cl_strerror(ret));;
    cl_engine_free(engine);
close(fd);
return 2;
}

/* scan file descriptor */
if((ret = cl_scandesc(fd, &virname, &size, engine, CL_SCAN_STDOPT)) == CL_VIRUS) {
printf("Virus detected: %s\n", virname);
} else {
if(ret == CL_CLEAN) {
    printf("No virus detected.\n");
} else {
    printf("Error: %s\n", cl_strerror(ret));
    cl_engine_free(engine);
    close(fd);
    return 2;
}
}
close(fd);

/* free memory */
cl_engine_free(engine);

/* calculate size of scanned data */
mb = size * (CL_COUNT_PRECISION / 1024) / 1024.0;
printf("Data scanned: %2.2Lf MB\n", mb);

return ret == CL_VIRUS ? 1 : 0;
}
```

each time i execute the code the following error are generated

```
error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'unistd.h': No such file or directory    C:\Users\Delta-W\Documents\New folder\clamav-0.97.8\CyberD\CyberD.cpp

IntelliSense: cannot open source file "clamav.h"    c:\users\delta-w\documents\new folder\clamav-0.97.8\cyberd\cyberd.cpp
```

although i have included clamav.h

kindly guide me if possible

Comment: Do you have this file in the Directory 'unistd.h'?? it yes search for other files(header files .h) and place this file with them.

Answer (score 2):

`io.h` seems to be the equivalent of `unistd.h` in Visual Studio.

Comment: thanx for the reply, and what about the second header file clamav.h

Comment: Yor example is ready for gcc, for Visual Studio take a look to oss.netfarm.it/clamav (a native Win32 Port)